# How do I remove duplicates using DELETE FROM and a sub-query?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-workbench

Notes:

- The return from `SELECT version()` is 10.5.12-MariaDB-log
- Default collation: utf8mb4_unicode-ci
- Default charset: utf8mb4
- Queries run using MySQL Workbench for Ubuntu Linux 8.0.29

My goal is to delete duplicated items in a table. I do not have any other table to use as a reference to check duplicates. I created a simple query and subquery that returns expected results:

```
    SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id NOT IN
        (SELECT id FROM
            messages
        WHERE
            uid = '11899414026778263'
        GROUP BY message_id , uid
        ORDER BY created_at);
```

Despite setting SQL_SAFE_UPDATES to 0, a DELETE operation using the same data fails. I get a "QUERY Interrupted" message.

```
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
    DELETE FROM messages WHERE id NOT IN
        (SELECT id FROM
            messages
        WHERE
            uid = '11899414026778263'
        GROUP BY message_id , uid
        ORDER BY created_at);
    SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 1;
```

If I replace `DELETE` with `SELECT *`, the query returns results. Another StackOverflow answer said that querying based on a sub-query does not work in MySQL. Others say to use another table as reference instead of a subquery.
[DELETE query results in 'Query Interrupted' MySQL Workbench?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38641739/why-mysql-delete-is-unable-to-use-indexes-on-sub-queries)

This method works in some SQL implementations based on these answers and websites:

- [Delete Duplicates From a Table in SQL Server](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/delete-duplicates-sql-server/)
- [Different ways to SQL delete duplicate rows from a SQL Table](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-sql-delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-sql-table/)
- [How to delete duplicate rows in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18390574/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql-server)

Comment: your subquery doesn't seem appropriate to find duplicate rows.  can you explain how you mean for it to work?

Comment: @ysth There are rows with repeated combinations of `message_id` and `uid`. I want to delete those rows. There is a separate primary key for this table called `id`.

Comment: your inner query will (if you have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY off) find an arbitrary id for each message_id for the specified uid.  then the outer query deletes all other ids for that uid and *all* ids for any other uid.  surely you don't want that.

Comment: this kind of query indeed does not work in mysql, but that is fixed in mariadb.  using a join could still be better; queries with large IN sets are not optimized as well in all cases in my experience

Answer (score 0):

order by is applied after grouping, so your order by is not sufficient to select the id with the lowest created_at for each group.  Your query will fail under ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY because the id returned by the subselect will be arbitrary within each group.  You want to use first_value instead.

But it's easier just to not use a subquery:

```
delete m
from messages m
# is there a message we would prefer over this one?
inner join messages m2 on (m2.uid,m2.message_id)=(m.uid,m.message_id) and (m2.created_at,m2.id) < (m.created_at,m.id)
```

Comment: Hello. I cannot test this answer anymore since I just restored the database to a month-old version instead. It is missing some data but still works. If anyone finds this useful, please upvote this answer. If I happen to see many up-votes, I will accept this answer.