# WHY DELETE takes much longer than SELECT (but same primary key based DELETE is fast)

Tags: mysql

I would like to know why my DELETE on a MySQL 5.5 myisam table is sooo slow (i had to cancel it)

This SQL takes under a second:

```
SELECT id FROM backup
WHERE id > 0 
      AND userId NOT IN 
      (SELECT id FROM user WHERE state > 0) 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100;
```

This identical DELETE did not finish afte 2 Minutes (i canceled it)

```
DELETE FROM backup
WHERE id > 0 
      AND userId NOT IN 
      (SELECT id FROM user WHERE state > 0) 
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100;
```

But the following DELETE - **querying the SAME ROWS** (just now selected by their primary key directly) - took under a second to complete!

```
DELETE FROM backup WHERE id IN (12, 33, 34, [... 100 ids...])
```

EDIT
I also tried this modification using a sub-subquery - i canceld it after a minute...

```
DELETE FROM backup WHERE id IN (
    SELECT ID FROM (
        SELECT id FROM backup WHERE id > 0 
        AND userId NOT IN (SELECT id FROM user WHERE state > 0) 
        ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 100
    ) a 
);
```

Using INNER JOIN does not work with DELETE as i use ORDER BY.

Any idea?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Performance of sub-query in IN clause with large tables in delete query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39634970/performance-of-sub-query-in-in-clause-with-large-tables-in-delete-query)

Comment: … or [Very slow delete on mysql base with subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361174/very-slow-delete-on-mysql-base-with-subquery)

Comment: thank you, but i tried that - it did not help. see my edit...

Answer (score 0):

ok, the problem is in fact the subquery - respectively the **ORDER BY and LIMIT** statements.

when i omit order by and limit and use the following query, it is as fast as expected (under a second):

```
DELETE backup FROM backup 
INNER JOIN user ON user.id = backup.userId
WHERE backup.id > 0 AND backup.id < 276 AND (state = 0 OR state IS NULL);
```